# Django cache function taking too much time

Tags: django, caching, django-rest-framework, redis

I need help with the django caching I am using django cache function to cache the currency conversion of a currency for 24 hours, I am using redis for caching and redis is a container at same place as django container in a docker compose file.

this is the function

`def getExchangeRate(currencyCode: str) -> float:
# Define a cache key based on the currency code
cache_key = f'exchange_rate_{currencyCode}'

```
# Check the cache first for the exchange rate
exchangeRate = cache.get(cache_key)

if exchangeRate is None:
    try:
        # Fetch the exchange rate from the database
        exchangeRate = float(ExchangeRate.objects.get(currency__code=currencyCode).rate)

        # Cache the fetched value with an appropriate TTL (e.g., 24 hours)
        cache.set(cache_key, exchangeRate, 86400)  # 86400 seconds = 24 hours
    except (ExchangeRate.DoesNotExist, ValueError):
        # Handle the case where the currency code is not found in the database
        # or the rate cannot be converted to a float
        exchangeRate = None
cache.close()
return exchangeRate`
```

the get function is taking too much time about 1700 ms which is I think way too much

The image attached is from atatus monitering which shows the get query is taking alot of time in a transection

[image]

I needed a currency conversion in my app which use a conversion value stored in database to multiply with and return to user on the basis of the currency selected by the user I tried using Django cache function to cache the value for 24 hours so we do not get the currency conversion value for all of the bookings as the conversion value stay same for a day but surprisingly redis get function is taking lot of time which is not ideal I tried searching dor a solution online but couldn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

the overall code looks ok. to check why it takes too long you can use [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html). however I don't understand why you close cache after if statement. probably you use cache for first time calling this function and it closes cache. then if you call this function as cache is closed, it enters if statement and taking too long to read data.